# ¿Como puedo realizar una bitacora de acceso a las paginas de un sitio web de un usuario en laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

Hola solicito su apoyo con el fin de implementar seguridad a un sitio web en laravel, realizar una bitácora de todos los accesos de un usuario, pero no se como capturar el url al cual accedió un usuario o la acción que ha ejecutado. Que me recomiendan?

Comment: Buenas, revisa [ask] y [mcve] para que te podamos ayudar mejor.

Comment: Realmente no es complicado de hacer, sin embargo no has aceptado la respuesta de tu anterior pregunta, ¿faltó algo?.

Comment: Si no es difícil que sugieres que haga, expresa tu idea por favor?